# Automatically-generated Python dbt test seems to be hardcoded to fail

Tags: dbt

I have a Python DBT project that defines the following data model (via YAML):

```
version: 2
models:
- name: company
  description: ''
  columns:
  - name: ID
    description: Unique identifier for the company entity. It is the company name
    tests:
      - unique
      - not_null
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
          column_type: VARCHAR
  - name: REMOTE_ID
    description: Company name
    tests:
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
          column_type: VARCHAR
  - name: CREATED_AT
    description: ''
    tests:
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
          column_type: TIMESTAMP_TZ
      - not_null
  - name: UPDATED_AT
    description: ''
    tests:
      - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
          column_type: TIMESTAMP_TZ
```

When I run `dbt compile`, then `dbt run` then `dbt test` I get a DBT test failure with the following console output:

```
17:59:30  Failure in test dbt_expectations_expect_column_values_to_be_of_type_company_CREATED_AT__TIMESTAMP_TZ (models/fizzbuzz/domain/company.yml)
17:59:30    Got 1 result, configured to fail if != 0
17:59:30  
17:59:30    compiled Code at target/compiled/myapp/models/fizzbuzz/domain/company.yml/dbt_expectations_expect_column_837854ce21e79ee1abe42f69891c68e9.sql
```

When I go to that compiled SQL at `dbt_expectations_expect_column_837854ce21e79ee1abe42f69891c68e9.sql` this is what I see:

```
WITH relation_columns
     AS (SELECT Cast('ID' AS VARCHAR)      AS relation_column,
                Cast('VARCHAR' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('REMOTE_ID' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column,
                Cast('VARCHAR' AS VARCHAR)   AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('CREATED_AT' AS VARCHAR)    AS relation_column,
                Cast('TIMESTAMP_NTZ' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('UPDATED_AT' AS VARCHAR)    AS relation_column,
                Cast('TIMESTAMP_NTZ' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type),
     test_data
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   relation_columns
         WHERE  relation_column = 'CREATED_AT'
                AND relation_column_type NOT IN ( 'TIMESTAMP_TZ' ))
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
```

So my *understanding* is that when I run `dbt compile` it generates this test above from the compiled YAML file definition. And that when I subsequently run `dbt test`, it runs this SQL to determine whether the test defined in that YAML passes or fails.

If that's correct, don't we have a bug in DBT here? Is it me or isn't this a false negative test that is hard-coded to always fail?!

It's creating a temp table/CTE called `test_data` that is in no way, shape or form connecting to my `company` database table, but that has 2 columns (`relation_column` and `relation_column_type`). Then its giving this table a row where the `relation_column` value is "CREATED_AT" and its `relation_column_type` value is "TIMESTAMP_NTZ". And finally its returning any records whose `relation_column` value is "CREATED_AT" but whose `relation_column_type` value is **not** "TIMESTAMP_NTZ"...so wouldn't this always fail?!

Or am I missing something **big** about how DBT and its tests work? Thanks for any clarifications here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking into it the DBT community no longer supports the `dbt test` command nor the DBT expectations offshoot project, likely for reasons just like this.

Comment: I don't agree. 0.10.0 version of dbt_expectations has been released in September '23

Answer (score 0):

You should not check target/complied but target/run.

There you will see that there is additional wrapper.
I suppose dbt actually runs something like this:

```
select
      count(*) as failures,
      count(*) != 0 as should_warn,
      count(*) != 0 as should_error
    from (

WITH relation_columns
     AS (SELECT Cast('ID' AS VARCHAR)      AS relation_column,
                Cast('VARCHAR' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('REMOTE_ID' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column,
                Cast('VARCHAR' AS VARCHAR)   AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('CREATED_AT' AS VARCHAR)    AS relation_column,
                Cast('TIMESTAMP_NTZ' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Cast('UPDATED_AT' AS VARCHAR)    AS relation_column,
                Cast('TIMESTAMP_NTZ' AS VARCHAR) AS relation_column_type),
     test_data
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   relation_columns
         WHERE  relation_column = 'CREATED_AT'
                AND relation_column_type NOT IN ( 'TIMESTAMP_TZ' ))
SELECT *
FROM   test_data     

) dbt_internal_test
```

So dbt tests results are always in form of table. By default if inner test query returns number of rows > 0 then test fails. But you can pass to your test definition in yaml, let's say:
tests:
- expect_column_value_lengths_to_equal:
value: 10
shold_warn: ">30"
should_error: ">100"
- not_null

This should cause your dbt_expectations test to fail when you have more than 100 number of rows where length different than 10.

Tests for data type are made to fail whenever result of test is a table with number of rows > 0.

Take a look how not_null test works in dbt (target/run folder):

```
select
      count(*) as failures,
      count(*) != 0 as should_warn,
      count(*) != 0 as should_error
    from (
      
    
    



select my_column
from "my_database"."my_schema"."my_table"
where my_column is null



      
    ) dbt_internal_test
```